# Socket connection reset still not understood

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

What is the problem:

It appears that spuriously a Java Socket based server program resets it's connection to a Java socket based client in the midst of an established connection, despite SO_TIMEOUT settings for data transfer being set to "infinite"

I tested the server on:

Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Kernel 3.13.0-29-generic Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b04)
and on
Windows 8.1 Version 6.3.9600 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)

And there is a difference. On Windows the server doesn't accept connections when all threads are busy and the backlog is used and so it should be. On Linux connections are accepted, data can be written and flushed (in addition with TCP_NODELAY) but at a subsequent read by the client its receives "Connection Reset" every now and then. I get no exceptions at the server side.
There is no change in behaviour if the client is ran under Windows or Linux, nor is there any difference running the server on a loopback address, a local network address or and external network address.

Any help or contributions would be very welcome. I'm here to learn too, so if I made coding errors just tell me.

In earlier posts there was no source added rather than a link to a JAR and source images on my website. I agree this is no common practice here, so I made a condensed version which also reveals the problem. Note that all settings are deliberately chosen to bring the server in an overloaded state and timeouts for connections and reads are set to "infinite". I do realize that these are not the ones one would choose in "real life", but merely to generate the "Connection Reset".

This is the code for the client:

```
package resetconntest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class MiniClient {

  static boolean SHOW_EXC_ONLY = true;   // show exceptions only
  static int     THREADS       = 64;     // number of "simultaneous connections"
  static int     LOOPS         = 256;    // total number of connections
  static String  HOST          = "192.168.0.10"; // server hostname 
  static int     PORT          = 7272;           // server port
  static int     CONN_TIMEOUT  = 0;      // keep infinite connect time for test
  static int     SO_TIMEOUT    = 0;      // keep infinite read    time for test
  static int     SO_LINGER     = -1;     // no linger
  static boolean REUSE_ADDRESS = false;  // chosen for test
  static boolean TCP_NODELAY   = true;   // small blocks, so no Nagle 
  static boolean KEEP_ALIVE    = false;  // chosen for test
  static int     TRAFFIC_CLASS = 0;      // if used, use mask as for ToS

  public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    new MiniClient().runTest ();
    System.exit ( 0 );
  }

  MiniClient () {}

  void runTest () {
    Object syncer = new Object();
    System.out.println ( "--> start MiniClient" );
    try {
      Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore ( THREADS );
      for ( int x = 0 ; x < LOOPS ; x++ ) {
        semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly ();
        new Requester ( syncer ,x + 1 ,semaphore ).start(); 
      }
      while ( semaphore.availablePermits() < THREADS ) {
        Thread.sleep ( 100 );
      }
    } catch ( Throwable anyThrown ) {
      synchronized ( syncer ) {
        System.out.println ( "--> throwable in main" );
        anyThrown.printStackTrace ( System.out );
        System.out.println ( "<-- throwable in main" );
      }
    }
    System.out.println ( "<-- end MiniClient" );
  }

  class Requester extends Thread {
    Object    syncer;
    String    index;
    Semaphore semaphore;

    Requester ( Object syncer ,int index ,Semaphore semaphore ) {
      this.syncer    = syncer;
      this.index     = Integer.toString ( index );
      this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    public void run () {
      try {
        Socket socket = new Socket ();
        socket.connect         ( new InetSocketAddress ( HOST ,PORT ) ,CONN_TIMEOUT );
        socket.setSoTimeout    ( SO_TIMEOUT );
        socket.setSoLinger     ( (SO_LINGER >= 0) ,SO_LINGER );
        socket.setReuseAddress ( REUSE_ADDRESS );
        socket.setTcpNoDelay   ( TCP_NODELAY );
        socket.setKeepAlive    ( KEEP_ALIVE );
        if ( TRAFFIC_CLASS != 0 ) socket.setTrafficClass ( TRAFFIC_CLASS );
        PrintWriter    out = new PrintWriter    ( new OutputStreamWriter ( socket.getOutputStream() ) );
        BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader  ( socket.getInputStream()  ) );

        if ( dialog ( "aaaaa" ,out ,in ) )
        if ( dialog ( "bbbbb" ,out ,in ) )
             dialog ( "close" ,out ,in );

        socket.shutdownInput();
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close ();
      } catch ( Throwable anyThrown ) {
        synchronized ( syncer ) {
          System.out.println ( "--> throwable in client thread:" + index );
          anyThrown.printStackTrace ( System.out );
          System.out.println ( "<-- throwable in client thread:" + index );
        }
      }
      semaphore.release ();
    }

    boolean dialog ( String         text
                    ,PrintWriter    out 
                    ,BufferedReader in ) throws Throwable {
      String msg = index + ':' + text;
      try {
        if ( SHOW_EXC_ONLY == false ) synchronized ( syncer ) { System.out.println ( "--> send: " + msg ); }
        out.println ( msg );
        out.flush();
        String resp = in.readLine();
        if ( resp == null ) {
          synchronized ( syncer ) { System.out.println ( "<-- got EOF after: " + msg ); }
          return false;
        }
        if ( SHOW_EXC_ONLY == false ) synchronized ( syncer ) { System.out.println ( "<-- received: " + resp ); }
      } catch ( Throwable anyThrown ) {
        synchronized ( syncer ) {
          System.out.println ( "--> throwable in client thread:" + index );
          System.out.println ( "--> at processing message: " + msg );
          anyThrown.printStackTrace ( System.out );
          System.out.println ( "<-- at processing message: " + msg );
          System.out.println ( "<-- throwable in client thread:" + index );
        }
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  } // end of inner class

} // end of code
```

And this is the code for the server:

```
package resetconntest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class MiniServer {

  static boolean SHOW_EXC_ONLY        = false;  // show messages and exceptions
  static String  HOST                 = "192.168.0.10";  // host name   binded to
  static int     PORT                 = 7272;            // port number binded to 
  static int     ACC_TIMEOUT          = 0;      // keep timeout for accept infinite for test
  static boolean REUSE_SERVER_ADDRESS = false;  // chosen for test
  static int     BACKLOG              = 2;      // keep low for test
  static int     THREADS              = 8;      // keep low for test
  static int     SO_TIMEOUT           = 0;      // keep infinite read timeout for test
  static int     SO_LINGER            = -1;     // no lingering
  static boolean REUSE_ACC_ADDRESS    = false;  // chosen for test
  static boolean TCP_NODELAY          = true;   // small blocks, so no Nagle
  static boolean KEEP_ALIVE           = false;  // chosen for test
  static int     TRAFFIC_CLASS        = 0;      // if used, use mask as for ToS
  static int     PROCESS_DELAY        = 500;    // simulate long message processing 0.5 sec

  public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    new MiniServer().runTest ();
    System.exit ( 0 );
  }

  MiniServer () {}

  public void runTest () {
    Object syncer = new Object();
    System.out.println ( "--> start MiniServer" );
    try {
      InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress ( InetAddress.getByName ( HOST ), PORT );
      ServerSocket      serverSocket  = new ServerSocket ();
      serverSocket.bind            ( socketAddress ,BACKLOG );
      serverSocket.setReuseAddress ( REUSE_SERVER_ADDRESS );
      serverSocket.setSoTimeout    ( ACC_TIMEOUT );
      Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore ( THREADS );
      Socket    accepted;
      while ( true ) {
        semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly();
        accepted = serverSocket.accept();
        new Servicer ( syncer ,accepted ,semaphore ).start(); 
      }
      // never reached, gives the warning at server construction.
      // to end the server, just use the old fashioned blunt CTRL-C
      // while ( semaphore.availablePermits() < THREADS ) {
      //   Thread.sleep ( 100 );
      // }
      // serverSocket.close ();
    } catch ( Throwable anyThrown ) {
      synchronized ( syncer ) {
        System.out.println ( "--> throwable in main" );
        anyThrown.printStackTrace ( System.out );
        System.out.println ( "<-- throwable in main" );
      }
    }
    System.out.println ( "<-- end MiniServer" );
  }

  class Servicer extends Thread {
    Object    syncer;
    Socket    socket;
    Semaphore semaphore;

    Servicer ( Object    syncer
              ,Socket    socket
              ,Semaphore semaphore ) { 
      this.syncer    = syncer;
      this.socket    = socket;
      this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    public void run () {
      try {
        socket.setSoTimeout    ( SO_TIMEOUT );
        socket.setSoLinger     ( (SO_LINGER >= 0) ,SO_LINGER );
        socket.setReuseAddress ( REUSE_ACC_ADDRESS );
        socket.setTcpNoDelay   ( TCP_NODELAY );
        socket.setKeepAlive    ( KEEP_ALIVE );
        if ( TRAFFIC_CLASS != 0 ) socket.setTrafficClass ( TRAFFIC_CLASS );
        BufferedReader in =  new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader  ( socket.getInputStream()  ) );
        PrintWriter    out = new PrintWriter   ( new OutputStreamWriter ( socket.getOutputStream() ) );
        String         clientMessage;
        while ( true ) {
          clientMessage = in.readLine ();
          if ( clientMessage == null ) {
            synchronized ( syncer) { System.out.println ( "<-> received end of file from accepted socket" ); }
            break;
          }
          if ( SHOW_EXC_ONLY == false ) synchronized ( syncer ) { System.out.println ( "client said: " + clientMessage ); }
          if ( PROCESS_DELAY > 0 ) Thread.sleep ( PROCESS_DELAY );
          out.println ( "echo: " + clientMessage );
          out.flush();
          if ( clientMessage.indexOf ( "close" ) >= 0 ) break;
        }
        socket.shutdownInput();
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
      } catch ( Throwable anyThrown ) {
        synchronized ( syncer ) {
          System.out.println ( "--> throwable in server thread" );
          anyThrown.printStackTrace ( System.out );
          System.out.println ( "<-- throwable in server thread" );
        }
      }
      semaphore.release();
    }

  } // end of inner class

} // end of code
```

Comment: Unless you have a specific question your post is out of scope for this site.

Comment: Can you explain why? I just got a Java programming problem which I describe verbally. I see numerous post from people having the same type of problems with the issue I adress.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); 
[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is there a firewall between your client and server?

Comment: Your question isn't answerable in its current form. It consists of a description of what you *think* the application does, and a link to a large amount of offsite code which nobody is going to follow. This isn't a free debugging service. You owe it to yourself, as well as to the users of this site, to make some effort. Reduce your code to the minimal form that exhibits the problem and post it here. Ten to one you will spot the error yourself in the process. It's called debugging.

Comment: Don't ask me, I think I came up with a quite clear simple topic, especially if you would follow the link in my post. As for you: give it a try and .... like on all media: there may be trolls around.

Comment: No there is no firewall between, I'm on my local network.

Comment: I'm not thinking what the appilcation does, I wrote the applications for both server and client side EJP. And the problem is decribed clearly in my post. So for you once again: It seems that for some reason in the midst of an established(!) dialog the connection is reset. And yes, I suspect an underlying problem in the VM, just read or google and you'll find numerous messages that are related to this issue, manifested in various environments and Java based systems but t.m.o. related to this basic level. And if you really want to see some code: follow the link or even have a try yourself.

Comment: I don't need to 'try myself'. My code works. Millions of lines of it. That's because it does what I think it does. Yours doesn't. It throws unexpected exceptions instead. That's because of a bug in your code. The code you refuse to take normal debugging steps about, or even exhibit here in a minimal form that exhibits the problem. That's your problem. You think it's perfect when it isn't, and you're just avoiding the issue by postulating non-existent bugs in any component but your own perfect code. It ain't so.

Comment: EJP I think our discussion is closed (unless you point where my code is wrong, of course ....)

Comment: Seriously, you expect us to debug server and client code which suffers from an intermittent bug by just looking at pages and pages of text?  You don't even know which end the problem is, or even if there is a problem with the code at all - it may be network-related.  The only sane way to debug this is with the same environment as you, with compiled code and debugging/logging.  There is only one with such resources - that would be you.

Comment: No James, you can get the complete JAR with all compiled classes and sources at the link mentioned in the original post. And for the enviroment: with the test program you can configure whatever you want. I agree, this is not a 'have a look at my code' post because I did my best to produce a very flexible test-suite so that everyone interested can prove me wrong, like EJP, concerning my code.

Comment: @user3735839 I already know where it's wrong. Same as all the other answers to this question. You're writing to a connection that had already been closed by the peer. When and if you post code here in the form requested, I'll demonstrate it to you. But you seem to be more interested in arguing than in fixing your problem. Good luck with that.

Comment: Did you have a look at any code?, apparently not. If you would have analyzed the timelines in the client-server dialog you would have seen that at the moment of the 'connection reset' at the client size, always on the 'aaaa' message, the server side cannot be in the closed state already. And, as said before the problem is not occurring at writing but at reading ..... But anyway, thank you for your response.

Comment: Ok, I will make a new post with a short version of the client and server code (each about 120 lines) revealing the same. Would that suit you ?

Comment: I didn't say it happened on write. I said it is usually *caused by* writing to a connection that the peer has already closed. The other major cause is fiddling around with the SO_LINGER option, which you should simply never do. In either case the exception can occur on either read or write.

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.setSoLinger( (SO_LINGER >= 0) ,SO_LINGER );
```

Get rid of this line completely, in both server and client. This is the other way to provoke connection resets, besides what I said in comments. Just remove it. You don't need it. It's a problem, not a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and I tried it immediately. But alas, no change except that I got maybe a few less "Connection Reset" but a few "Connection Timeout" at connecting to the server, as it should be. I am delaying consecutive accept() calls on the ServerSocket by maximizing the number of threads, using the semaphore and simulating long processing time, I'm aware of that, I do that deleberately to stress the server. Could it be that I violate some timing scheme I don't know of ?

Comment: I "Wiresharked" the dialog and indeed the server side did send an RST But for what reason ?

Comment: EJP, suddenly lost interest? BTW: I made a mistake in my first post, behaviour in Windows8 is the same after all as in Linux (Debian) and that is that a stressed server spuriously sends a Reset in the midst of a read/write dialog on an established connection (now I really saw it "WireSharking" the connection). It may take time before the connection comes alive (due to the thread-limiting semaphore) but once its there client and server starts interchanging data on a "live connection". I added a fairly long (.5sec) delay in the dialog, but that could occur in real life occasionally as well

Comment: And are you convinced that there is no issue of streams having been closed prematurely or anything like that often referred to in other post about this subject? In my tests the connections are established, streams are created and then it happens every now and then: Some dialogs crash, most others run perfectly. Did you discover any other flaws in my test-code ?

Comment: If your server is running on Windows and the listen backlog queue fills up, further incoming connections will be refused with an RST. On other platforms they will be ignored, which will cause connect timeouts. Is that your question now?